# 404 GET /app/app.module error 404 GET /@angular/platform-browser-dynamic

Tags: angular

I tried importing angular material and npm installed and now my whole app broke, and I don't know where it went wrong. I changed configs in systems.js and package.json, and I am getting 404 GET error on both @angular/platform-browser-dynamic and app/app.module. Can anyone please show me where I went wrong?? Thanks so much!!!

this is my main.ts:

```
// main entry point
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

import { EmployeeFilterPipe } from './employees/employee-filter.pipe'

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { DataService } from './shared/data.service';
import {EmployeesListComponent} from './employees/employees-list.component';
import { EmployeeDetailComponent } from './employees/employee-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'employees', component: EmployeesListComponent},
      {path: 'employee/:id', component: EmployeeDetailComponent }
    ], {useHash: true})
   ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeesListComponent,
    EmployeeFilterPipe,
    EmployeeDetailComponent
   ],
  providers: [ DataService, EmployeeFilterPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",

    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",

    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",

    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"

  }
}
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js'

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

And this is the error message I get on chrome dev tool:

```
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
        at XMLHttpRequest.desc.set.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic as "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" from http://localhost:3000/main.js
```

Comment: Don't think this is the problem, but your `EmployeeFilterPipe` shouldn't need to be in both the `Declarations` and the `Providers` arrays.  It only needs to be in the `Declarations` array in the NgModule.

Comment: I had to put them in both to make the filter work. I'm still getting the 404 error even if I remove the `EmployeeFilterPipe` from the `Providers` array..

Answer (score 4):

I sort of figured out why the browser couldn't find `platform-browser-dynamic`. 
The browser was looking for `http://localhost:3000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` when the folder is actually in `http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`.

So I had to manually change the path in systemsjs file, to: 
`'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js'`,
since it wasn't reading the alias path of npm:..
so now my systemsjs file looks like this:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',

  // other libraries
  'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
  });

})(this);
```

I know it's not the most optimal solution and i don't understand why the systemsjs file wasn't applying alias path to this, but it fixed the problem for now. if anyone has more accurate solution, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!